# create full url from rails string representation of url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Is there a way to get a full path url from the shorthand-string representation of routes in rails?

Ie from the rake routes output, a string of `terms#index` that creates the full path to where it maps, eg `http://what-ever.com/terms-and-conditions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `url_for` could help you? [Documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for). Its not using the exact string but depending on what you're doing maybe you could get a similar result by placing the variables inside.

Something like:

```
<%= url_for(:action => '#{action}', :controller => '#{controller}', :only_path => false %>
```

Just a guess. Don't actually know if it will work :).

Answer (score 0):

If

```
rake routes --trace
          terms GET    /terms(.:format)             terms#index
```

Then I think following will work

```
terms_path #Gives /terms
```

and

```
terms_url #Gives http://what-ever.com/terms
```

Comment: yeah that's fine, but i want a way to generate the path from the string `controller#action`